# wrong downloadname aspx

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm using this method to download a file from somewhere on my aspx page called: downloader.aspx

```
byte[] virtualPath = client.DownloadData(link/file.doc);
Response.BinaryWrite(virtualPath);
```

However, when the client shows the download it tells me:
"Do you want to download `downloader.doc` from mywebsite.com?
It does not show the original name.

Is there a way to use the original name (`file.doc`) instead of the name of the aspx page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the response header `Content-Disposition` to set the filename.

```
byte[] virtualPath = client.DownloadData(link/file.doc);
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=file.doc");
Response.BinaryWrite(virtualPath);
```

Comment: why did you change the AddHeader to AppendHeader?

Comment: Technically, `AddHeader` is deprecated, and they encourage you to use `AppendHeader` in the documentation ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.addheader.aspx ). Shouldn't matter to you in the end; the net result should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can use http response header field  content dispostion.
See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/content-disposition/info

Try the following

```
byte[] virtualPath = client.DownloadData(link/file.doc);
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +"file.doc");
Response.BinaryWrite(virtualPath);
Response.End();
```

Comment: Thanks, but the other answer was easier to use.
`Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=file.doc");
`